# ExecutionEngineException using ArcGIS 10.0 extension recompiled for 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, .net

I have a written an ArcGIS extension in C# .Net for version 10.0.  I have attempted to recompile this extension for 10.1 and that works.  But running the extension in 10.1 is causing ArcGIS to crash.  While debugging the code I'm getting an error saying "ExecutionEngineException was unhandled". This is not always happening on the same part of the code.  One time its a cursor, another time its setting symbology, etc.  its different every time.

I have read through the documentation [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Migrating_ArcGIS_9_3_x_and_10_Desktop_and_Engine_custom_components_to_ArcGIS_10_1/0001000002m2000000/) on how to upgrade and none of these solutions are helping.

Has anyone ever experienced this before?  I have no idea what else to try.